# jQuery UI tabs loading text files don't preserve newlines

Tags: jquery-ui, newline, jquery-ui-tabs

The following code loads a txt file content in a new tab. But it doesn't preserve newlines even though the content is inside a `<pre>` tag:

**multiline.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.css" type="text/css"></link>
<style>
pre {
  border: 1px red solid !important;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs({panelTemplate: '<pre></pre>'});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>PRE TAG:</h3>
  <pre>
  Multi
  line
  FTW
  </pre>
  <h3>jQueryUI-loaded PRE TAG:</h3>
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="multiline.txt">Tab</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**multiline.txt:**

```
I'm line #1
And I'm line #2
Guess what! I'm #3

And woohoo I'm #4 but I wanted to be alone!
```

As an alternative, I tried to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arnley/8y5v5/4/), with no success since the browser will yell at me with cross-origin loading error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per jQueryUI [ticket #7669](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7669), it can't be done with the `tabs` widget.

> Remote tabs expect to load HTML, not plaintext.

Answer (score 1):

You could try wrapping the text with a **pre** tag:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

Comment: Done that. Didn't change. My ultimate goal is to use Ajax.org's ACE editor to edit some local files in a Windows environment (should work in others too though). Ance ACE does use the `<pre>` tag already.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, HTML parsing ignores line breaks.  If you want it to render with the line breaks, you need to add `<br />` tags.

```
I am line #1 <br />
I am line #2 <br />
I am line #3 <br />
```

**EDIT**: Since you don't have access to the source, you can do something like this (using "content" ID as placeholder for actual container DIV id, replace with your own.):

```
$("#content").html( $("#content").html().replace("\n","<br />") );
```

Comment: I can't alter the source files. That isn't an option for me.

Comment: I fully understand your proposition but this can't be applied here since `$("#content").html()` doesn't contain any '\n'. These are missing, hence my post.

Comment: I'm assuming that since you're pulling in the content via AJAX that you are attempting to view the source via Firebug or something similar - if that's the case, when you're viewing the code in the HTML tab, the newlines still don't get displayed in the console, but they are still there.  I confirmed this by doing: `$('body').append("<div>line 1 \n line2 </div>");` , and when viewing the source it **appears** the newlines aren't there, but they are just being ignored by the parser.  Just for reference, have you tried doing the suggested replacement and can 100% confirm that it's not working?

Comment: Interesting. I'll try your solution as soon as I get back to work :)

Comment: Please check my post. I just updated it a few minutes ago. It makes it all clearer and proves that a `<pre>` tag is used. Even though, it doesn't keeps newlines.